# Include javascript variable inside php tags

Tags: php, javascript, echo

i have javascript as below

```
 html="<th>"+<?php echo __(); ?>+"</th>";
```

I want to add another javascript variable inside `to __()` function like this

```
<?php echo __(<js varible>); ?>
```

I tried

```
var myvarible=200;
html="<th>"+<?php echo __("'"+myvarible+"'"); ?>+"</th>";
console.log(html);
```

not working for me

can any one help me please
regards

Comment: echo __() is symfony localization function have to use it

Comment: Maybe you should better explain what you are trying to achieve. In general when you get to the point where you think you need to mix JS and PHP a big red alarm light should start flashing and you should start rethinking your strategy.

Comment: can you post your actual code (the code you are using).. may be that will help to better understand what you are trying to achieve and what APPROACH you have used...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding on how server side and client side code work.

The only way that you could possibly achieve what you are trying to do (apply a PHP localization function to a Javascript variable) would be like this (this code assumes you are using JQuery but can be done without it too):

```
var myvariable = 'hello';
$.get('http://yoursite.com/localize.php?text='+myvariable, function(localizedText) {
  html = "<th>"+localizedText+"</th>";
  console.log(html);
});
```

And then localize.php should look like this:

```
<?php
include('you localization library');
echo __($_GET['text']);
?>
```

***Explanation***: while your client side code (Javascript) is been executed in the browser it will call a URL which will execute your server side code (your PHP __(); function) in the server and then return the value to the client side code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myvarible=200;
html="<th>"+<?php echo __("'"+myvarible+"'"); ?>+"</th>";
console.log(html);
```

This would try to put the PHP variable "myvariable" into the script tag, what you want is closer to:

```
var myvarible=200;
html="<th>"+"<?php echo __("'myvarible'"); ?>"+"</th>";
console.log(html);
```

However, in this case, why not just skip PHP completely?

```
var myvarible=200;
html="<th>" + myvarible + "</th>";
console.log(html);
```

Comment: i cant skip it __echo() is localization function in symfony

Comment: what is being localized in this case? as pointed out elsewhere, the JS can't see/use the PHP localization, and the PHP can't see/localize the JS variable

Comment: why are you trying to localize an integer?

Comment: @Roshan: ah well as long as you dont need the variable to be dynamically determined from other functions in the JS then you'll be ok with my example. If on the otherhand you need to set `myvariable` from kind of action happening on the js side of things youre out of luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript runs on client side and php on server side. 
So `var myvarible=200;`
will be executed only on client side .

but  will be get executed on server side. at that time `myvariable` will not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myvariable='<?php echo __("200"); ?>';
html="<th>"+myvariable+"</th>";
console.log(html);
```

However for this to work the javascript would need to be in a .php file that is being interpreted.

> > The OP wants to include a JS variable in a PHP call, which is not possible, unless you use AJAX. And you'll agree with me that code like this is only meant to cause big headaches and should be avoided at all costs.

Well yes and no.. i wouldnt do it this way. I use a helper that lets me do things like this in a consistent way. In my view file i have something like:

```
<?php js_call('jslib.myFunction(?,?)', __($value), 'some other value'); ?>
```

`js_call` its similar to using `sprintf` or a prepared statement except for js. The params are run through `json_encode` so the quoting and what not are correct. All these are stored in an array and then in the layout, just before my `</body>` i call:

```
<?php include_js_calls(); ?>
```

which then takes all the calls ive made with a `js_call` and outputs the string values inside a script tag resulting in something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jslib.myFunction('first value', 'some other value');
</script>
```

Borrowed this brilliance from [Apostrophe Cms](http://apostrophenow.org)

Comment: This will NOT execute the PHP statement.

Comment: it will if its in a php file inside a script tag... which is IMO the only sane interpretation of what the OP posted :-) Its the same thign as echo'ing the output of `json_decode` into a script tag in your head to configure some js from dynamic php vars created when the page is processed on the server...

Comment: No, it will not, you have your `<?` tags inside a JS string that will only be parsed on the client.

Comment: no the result rendered to the client will be `var myvariable = 'RESULT OF PHP FUNCTION';` now if he tries to use a variable defined in the JS your statement would be tru but i passed the `200` into the php funciton on the server side as a string.

Comment: Ok, I was a bit hasty, it may actually be interpreted, but still you are hard coding the 200, the OP wants to *include a JS variable in a PHP call*, which is not possible, unless you use AJAX. And you'll agree with me that code like this is only meant to cause big headaches and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: but he already has the variable hard coded in the line above in his example... which is whay i said it was the only sane interpetation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed on the server, JS on the client. You cannot expect PHP to parse JS, in fact PHP will never see the JS statements, because they will be processed only once the server has processed the PHP.

Answer (score 1):

To do localization in javascript (for whatever reason), echo __() can obviously not be called directly.

There are different possible strategies

- Include a localization string table in javascript when the page loads. Do lookup against it when needed. This table could be generated on server-side using echo __() then cached.
- Make ajax requests for server-localized data. Might not be suitable for frequent updates.